# Script not "activating" cell for data entry

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a script set that unhides a page and selects a cell for editing. However, I notice that when the script runs, I have to "select" (click on) the cell again to allow for data to be written to that cell. Is there a better way than the code I have set running as seen below?

```
function class1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate(); 
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Class 1'), true); 
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
}
```

I want it to automatically allow data to be entered in A2 once the script has finished running but it seems to always stop that till I click on it and manually "activate" the cell.

Answer (score 1):

The `Range.activate()` method lets you *select* a cell, but it does not open the cell for editing. When a cell is selected, you can start typing to overwrite old contents in the cell, or press **Enter** to open the cell and edit its existing contents.

Your scriptlet can be shorted like this:

```
function class1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Class 1!A2').activate();
}
```

See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).